# Status of VPC and Midonet

Tags: eucalyptus

**Short verion:**

- -Is Midonet still on the roadmap for VPC support in Eucalyptus?
- -If so what version from their non-enterprise repo should work with Euca 4.4.5 VPC? (http://builds.midonet.org/)

**Long version with context:**
I was trying to install Eucalyptus 4.4.5 with VPC and midonet.  It appears that the enterprise midonet repos/services are not available and that Midokura isn't taking emails at sale@ or info@ addresses. This is broken for example: https://www.midokura.com/midonet-enterprise/

From my perspective it looks like Midokura dropped enterprise support entirely and midonet.org is the only resource available.

I took a swing at the installation with midonet 5.2 from their builds (http://builds.midonet.org/) based on the most recent Eucalyptus 4.4.5 install docs which specify enterprise version mem-5.2

Trying this I ran into tons of .rpm dependency issues installing on RHEL 7.6/7.7 and never got off the ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Midonet VPC support is currently planned for Eucalyptus 5.

5.2.x is the correct version, you would need these yum repositories enabled:

- http://builds.midonet.org/midonet-5.2/stable/el7/
- http://builds.midonet.org/misc/stable/el7/

Which use the gpg key:

- http://builds.midonet.org/midorepo.key

So something like:

```
# midokura.repo
[midokura]
name=Midokura Enterprise MidoNet
baseurl=http://builds.midonet.org/midonet-5.2/stable/el7/
enabled=1
fastestmirror_enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://builds.midonet.org/midorepo.key


#midokura-misc.repo
[midokura-misc]
name=MEM 3rd Party Tools and Libraries
baseurl=http://builds.midonet.org/misc/stable/el7/
enabled=1
fastestmirror_enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://builds.midonet.org/midorepo.key
```

Comment: Thanks, Steve.  This worked.  My dependency issue was not a collision with Euca vs Mido versions.  I found it actually came from the midonet 5.2 install guidance for cassandra.  They reference a datastax.com repo that is not current but still available.  I went straight to the Apache project for my cassandra install repos and instructions instead and had success.